# How can I use the 1 tag value in a post request?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to take the name from h1 tag in post request to nodejs and store it in database.

I got the quantity value,but name field is not updating.

see my htmlcode snippet below.

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="cake" id="0">
        <div class="text">
        <form method="POST" action="/cart">  
        <img src="/Cakes-images/cake2.jpg" alt="img1" id="img1">
        <h1 id="title" name = "name">Chocolate Delight</h1>
        <label>Select Qty:</label>
        <select id="cake" name="quantity">
            <option value="0.5Kg">0.5Kg</option>
            <option value="1Kg" selected>1Kg</option>
            <option value="2Kg">2Kg</option>
            <option value="3Kg">3Kg</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <button value="Add to cart" id="add-to-cart" >Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and my post request :

```js
router.post('/',async (req,res) => {
    
    console.log(req.params.name);
    const carts= new Cart({
        name:req.body.name,
        qty:parseInt(req.body.quantity)
    });

    //res.render('cartwithitem');

    try{
    const a= await carts.save();
    res.json(carts);
    console.log(carts);
    }catch(err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }    
})
```

Please let me now how can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you use an input tag instead of an h1 tag and make it looks like an h1? :)

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: I used input tag as hidden it worked thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h1>` elements are used to define the primary heading in a document.

They are not form controls. They do not have `name` attributes.

If you want a form to always submit data which is hard coded in the HTML (as opposed to being entered or selected by the user) then you need to use an `<input>` element of `type="hidden"` (with a `name` and `value`).

---

MDN has an [introductory guides to using forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) you might find useful as well as a [reference for the input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) which includes a section on [hidden inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).